# Prevent build concurrency in drone ci

Tags: drone.io

My Jenkins setup that provides this feature saves me alot of headache when I get 100 callbacks from services telling me that data has changed asking to rebuild the same build. If I ask for 100 new builds Jenkins just add one in the que pipeline without adding 100. It also has a option to wait for the last build to finish before starting a new one.

I found a old ticket https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/683 related to this and was suggested to ask it here first to see if the current version has a way of doing it. As far as i can tell there doesn't seem a option to achieve this?

http://docs.drone.io/pipelines/

Comment: More recent issue, still no solution though: [issue 758](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/758).  There is an option for per-agent concurrency but that probably doesn't help here: [isue comment](https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/758#issuecomment-375356605)